# Django on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - No module named MySQLdb Error

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run this web app for a while with no issues on Amazon's Linux version Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/**2.0.1**.

When I tried to "*upgrade*" to the latest Amazon Linux version: Python 2.7 version, Linux/**2.7.7** or any version after **2.0.1**, I get this error:

`ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb.`

`Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?`

I do have both installed and included in my `requirements.txt` file

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.14
```

I tried reinstalling them both and removing them one or the other from the requirements but still no luck.

in my .ebextensions I do have these:

```
packages:
    yum:
        python27-devel: []
        libmemcached-devel: []
        gcc: []
        libxml2-devel: []
        libxslt-devel: []
```

I have added the `gcc` and `libx` after that so I know they are not causing the error. (I did not try to remove the `python27-devel` or the `libmemcached-devel`

Any ideas?

What has changed beyond `2.0.1` since everything is working correctly running version `2.0.1` and it is not working on any newer EB version?

Comment: Can you share any configs you have in `.ebextensions`?

Comment: @MicahCarrick Yes I can! I have just updated my question and added those `.ebextrensions` above. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking through some past work, I think you may need to add `mysql-devel` to the `yum` section in your `.ebextensions` file

Comment: OMG! I just tried that on my "dev" server and got no error. I will run the production server update on Monday morning and will get back to you to reward the bounty. Thanks a million! I was going crazy and tried just about everything else.

Comment: Everything worked out great and I'm now running the latest AWS Linux version. Thanks again for the help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well, from what I can remember is you might need to rebuild the virtual env. In the elastic beanstalk console. Or using the eb command line interface.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, I have already tried that with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it just that one package, or is it happening on any other ones?

Comment: Just that one package. At least from the logs, it seem that this is the only issue.

Comment: When you run pip freeze what happens?

Comment: Locally? I get a long list of of packages installed in my `virt_env`. That being said, I dont include all of it in my `requiremetns.txt`as there are some older modules that I no longer need in my app.

Comment: No, on the server

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do that.Through the console?

Comment: @WayBehind I take it you did not configure SSH acces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185674/discussion-between-waybehind-and-kareem).

Answer (score 0):

Instead install

```
$ apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: Elasticbeanstalk runs Amazon Linus which doesn't use apt but instead uses yum.